# Centos randomly stops communication with public internet

Tags: linux, networking

When I try to install cPanel on fresh CentOS 6.5, it starts perfectly fine. It downloads packages and installs etc, and then it stops the install at a point. CentOS also cannot ping public internet, however it can ping local servers through public and private interfaces.

Edit; Server is behind NAT.

Symptoms are;

- I cannot ping public network (anything in the internet)
- I cannot ping gateway
- I can ping local servers through local interface
- I can ping public IPs of local servers through public interface
- I can still connect to SSH from its public and private interfaces
- I have remove iptables rules but it didnt helped.
- I have changed keep alive options from sysctl.conf but it didnt help
- I can only ping again the internet when I restart the machine

Edit; Restarting network worked this time.

Edit 2; I have made changes on tcp_keep_alive options and changed like this;

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 86400
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 20
```

These changes made the connection a bit better, what is happening right now is server still losts its connection but reconnects to network in a very short time.

Do you have any ideas about what is happening ?

I am a bit desperate right now :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you by any chance have a duplicated IP address? If your server is fighting with another one over who owns the IP address, that could give this kind of symptom. Otherwise, double check your routing both immediately on startup (when it works) and immediately after it works. Also, look in your system logs and any firewall logs.

Comment: Thanks for those tips Jenny, we are pretty sure that that ip is not used by some other server because we write firewall rules on those IPs. However I did not check the routing, let me check that.

Comment: Does the server's IP address change when this happens?  Anything from the network driver in `dmesg`?

Comment: @devicenull The weird point is there is no log about this and server does not change IP. However I will try to check if keep_alive option creates such problem.

Comment: 'Server is behind NAT'.. this is a pretty critical piece of information I didn't see before.  Are you sure the NAT device isn't running out of memory for the NAT table?

Comment: @devicenull sorry for not telling it before, I must have forgotten it. There is also another edit I have made. About tcp_keep_alive options. Also there is SRX3400 managing NAT's and it does have lots of resource to manage NAT, so I dont think the problem is on that.

Comment: SRX3400 should not run out of memory too soon I think. try to turn off the server, then ping the ip, to make sure no other server answer.

Comment: Does the SRC3400 have any kind of logs? If so, check those. Also the server routing, and maybe put a tcpdump going to see what goes on network-wise around the time that it loses connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

1) check default gateway

2) check DNS (resolve)

3) turn of server, and try to ping the ip of this host, to make sure no duplicate ip

4) print out dmsg and syslog after network goes from working to not working, look for cronjob set to do something at boot.

5) you seem to have several network cards on many servers, make sure your network does not have a loop. does other servers have any problems?  are both network cards accidentally on same vlan or on same dumb switch?

Comment: Thank you for your answer however we both checked and there is no problem with those.

Comment: the comments to the original question was getting a bit full, that is why I migrated over to an answer.

Comment: Hi Sverre, thank you again for your answers. We checked gateway and DNS unlimited times but we didnt see any problems. There cannot be IP problem because the IP pool is brand new and its all 10.8.X.X. DMESG and SYSLOG says nothing (this is where it becomes annoying) I will add my comments about network cards in next comment

Comment: Yes there are two network cards in each server. Each network card is on different VLAN and it is connected to different converged network cards.